# PrintVisual showing save dialog in wpf c#

Tags: wpf, grid, c#-3.0

I am using wpf printdialog()
I want to print direct but there is showing save dialog to save in pdf first then print.
Here is my code.

```
 PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();

        pd.PrintVisual(grid1, lblgr.Content.ToString() + "_" + lblreceiptno.Content);
```

Answer (score 0):

I get exact solution for your problem.

**PDFCreator Installed**

You are getting above problem because PDFCreator is installed on your development Machine and it is set as Default Printer in your Machine. That's why it's asking for save before printing of the document. So please go to Control Panel->View Devices and Printers and in that set your required Printer or network Printer as Default Printer and it will directly print your document and will not ask for saving it.

**PDFCreator not Installed**

If you have still have this issue and PDFCreator not installed on your machine then please set your required printer as Default printer and it will solves the issue.